# Submitting Form in Angularjs with ng-repeat items

Tags: forms, angularjs

So I am fairly new with angularjs and am having some problems submitting my form which has an ng-repeat inside. My problem is that after submitting the form, the only values I obtain are from the last row. I was hopeing that the objects would contain an array of all the values.

My form (sorry alittle messy after tinkering with it so much)

```
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" name="addEventsForm">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12" ng-repeat="item in Team.games">
                <div class="input-group col-xs-2" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.date" name="date" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" is-open="$parent.opened[$index]" min-date="minDate"  datepicker-options="dateOptions"  ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, $index)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-1" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addEventsForm.time.$invalid && !addEventsForm.time.$pristine }">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" ng-model="item.time" name="time" ng-blur="edit()"/>
                    <p ng-show="addEventsForm.time.$invalid && !addEventsForm.time.$pristine" class="help-block">Time is required.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-3" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addEventsForm.title.$invalid && !addEventsForm.title.$pristine }">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" ng-model="item.title" ng-blur="edit()" value="{{ item.awayTeam }} at {{ item.homeTeam }}" ng-minlength="1" ng-requred="true"/>
                    <p ng-show="addEventsForm.title.$invalid && !addEventsForm.title.$pristine" class="help-block">Title is required.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-2" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : addEventsForm.description.$invalid && !addEventsForm.discription.$pristine }">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" ng-model="item.description" ng-blur="edit()" value="{{ item.venue }}" ng-maxlength="50" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-3" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control geoLocation" name="location" ng-model="item.location" placeholder="Enter a location">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(Team.games, $index)">Remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="form-actions pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submit(addEventsForm)" data-loading-text="Importing...">
                <span class="icon icon-plus-fill" ></span>
                Import Events
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and I have no code in my js file just a function I am using to see the values that are being passed in through

Comment: Could you paste your js file content ? your complete form html content ?

Comment: My js only includes a function called submit that alerts the form. No actions are added yet. That is indeed my whole form.

Comment: At least use console.log this way you will be able to look in your data on an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have the same `name` attribute acrosse all repetitions. If you want them as an array you could prepend `$index` to your name attribute. $index is the number of iterations you have in done in your loop (See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)).

So in the end your form would produce an array containing a sub object for each iteration.

You will not be able to simply put $index in front of your name attribute though. I don't know exactly how to do it but maybe using `ng-attr` and playing around can solve your issue.

Comment: unfortunately I tried this already, the index properly gets added when inspecting the element but when checking the value it sends it changes to name: date_{{$index}} for example and not detecting the differently

Comment: Continue digging this way, it is the way to go. I suggest you make it `$index.date` This way it will create one object for each repetition of your template. You will probably have to overload the submit function of your form to do the work properly maybe that [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) can help.